# DevExpress GridView Auto Size Columns

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I'm trying to get **all** of my columns to expand so that the title of the columns are fully visible. I am not bothered about expanding based on the values as some columns contain long values - if needed I can expand these out manually in the UI.

But i cant seem to get the Column names to expand so they're visible. I've tried something like this in my form load event:

```
        con.open()
        com = New SqlCommand('SQL Command to return data is here')
        DataTable.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
        GridControl1.DataSource = DataTable
        GridControl1.DataMember = DataTable.TableName
        con.close()

    GridView1.OptionsBehavior.Editable = True
    GridView1.OptionsBehavior.AutoExpandAllGroups = True
    GridView1.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = True
    GridView1.OptionsView.BestFitMaxRowCount = -1
    GridView1.VertScrollVisibility = True
    GridView1.HorzScrollVisibility = True
```

But the code still returns the bellow output. I have both the scroll bars visible so I don't see why the table isn't expanding out and using the horizontal scroll bar to 'slide' to see more.

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

[image: Figure 1]

Also, I'm using the DevExpreses's GridControl.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, here's what I did:

```
    con.open()
    com = New SqlCommand('SQL Select Statement')
    DataTable.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
    GridControl1.DataSource = DataTable
    GridControl1.DataMember = DataTable.TableName
    con.close()

    GridView1.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = False
    GridView1.OptionsView.BestFitMaxRowCount = -1
    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
```